# ImportError: cannot import name 'types' Even though I installed google-cloud

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, google-cloud-vision

I am making a program right now and I am failing at the imports. I am just importing google.cloud.vision and from google.cloud.vision I am importing types as my code

```
import os, io
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
```

says. I am not getting an error when installing google.cloud in the second line but only at the third line and I don't know why since I am not failing at the second line? I already installed both google-cloud and google-cloud-vision using `pip install google-cloud` and `pip install google-cloud-vision`

Answer (score 1):

I believe `types` is in the `vision_v1` namespace. Try the following:

`from google.cloud.vision_v1 import types`

https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/vision_v1/types.html